# Get id from table based on sum of one field

Tags: sql

I have data in a table

**Name**                       **Amount**

Name1                      1000

Name2                      2000

Name3                      3000

Name4                      4000

I want to make a sql query and want to get this output

Sum of **Amount** is 3000
Name1
Name2

Sum of **Amount** is 5000
Name2
Name3

Sum of **Amount** is 6000
Name1
Name2
Name3

Comment: It can also be `Sum of amount is 5000 Name1 Name4` which makes it more difficult. why don't you handle it on the application level? The key here is loop `:)`

Comment: yes it is also possible but i will use other conditions to handle it.

Comment: Why aren't you including Name4?  What combinations are you looking for?

Comment: yes several combination can be possible but i will filter the data using by other contions like date so name4 will be out of the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Oracle. But it is not perfect as your requirement is a bit unrealistic and should be handled on appl. level as J W suggested. Do not waste your time on queries:

```
SELECT id, amt
, SUM(amt) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) sum 
 FROM
 (
 SELECT 1 id, 1000 amt FROM dual
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 2 ,  2000 amt FROM dual
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 3 ,  3000 amt FROM dual
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 4 ,  4000 amt FROM dual
 )
 /

ID    AMT    SUM
----------------------
1    1000    1000
2    2000    3000
3    3000    5000
4    4000    7000 -- not as in your example
```